# GSheets chart label from cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets, charts

In Excel, you can replace a series' label with the contents of a cell by selecting the label once, then again, and then entering your cell reference in the formula bar (see Excel screenshot).

[image: Excel screenshot]

I'd like to achieve the same result in Google Sheets.

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in google sheets try like this:

[image]

Comment: Solid answer. Thank you for redboxing the key items.